# How to make a custom description/summary alert for when an alert is fired and when is resolved in grafana?

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts

I would like to send a different Summary annotation in grafana alerts in case the alert is firing or resolved

[Firing alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzWMw.png)

[Resolved Alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvcCZ.png)

As shown in the images, the firing's summary is saying that the value is above 92 that is equal to the resolved summary.
And I would like to write in the resolved summary someting like "the value is below  {{ $values.B0.Value }}"

Btw why does {{ $values.B0.Value }} shows the value before the alert is resolved (92)?
The B alert condition is to be above 0...